# Remove Debugging Button on Touchbar in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging, ios-simulator, macbookpro-touch-bar

how can I get rid of the debugging Button on the Touchbar when my app is running on a simulator.

Here´s what I mean. 
[image]

It is on all Apps i switch to until i stop the application